# How to create a measure that sums rows only where sales exists this and last year?

Tags: powerbi, dax, tabular

Hello community and DAX gurus!

I am trying to create a measure that calculates the total product sales for a specfic month only for does products that has been sold the same period last year.

Below is an illustration of what I want to achieve:
[image]

The first thing I did was to create a measure to calculate the Sales Amount for previous year:

```
Sales Amount PY = 
CALCULATE(
          [Sales Amount],
          SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DimDate[Datekey])
         )
```

The second thing I did was to create a Comparable range flag as measure:

```
ComparableRange = IF(FactSales[Sales Amount] = BLANK() || FactSales[Sales Amount PY] = BLANK(),0,1)
```

Third step I created a measure to calculate the total product sales:

```
Total Product Sales =
CALCULATE(
          FactSales[Sales Amount],ALL(DimProduct)
         )
```

The final step I want to calculate the total product sales only for does products being comparable.
I tried this solution but not getting it to work, it is only returning blank:

```
Total Product Sales Comparable =
var CompRangeTable = ADDCOLUMNS(FactSales,"@CompRange",[ComparableRange])
var FilteredTable = FILTER(CompRangeTable,[@CompRange] = 1)
return
CALCULATE(FactSales[Sales Amount],ALL(DimProduct),FilteredTable)
```

I also tried this solution but still getting blanks:

```
Total Product Sales Comparable =
var FilteredTable = FILTER(FactSales, [Sales Amount PY]*[Sales Amount]+0<>0)
return
CALCULATE([Sales Amount],ALL(DimProduct),FilteredTable)
```

[image]

I wonder if the issue is that the Comparable range flag doesn't evaluate during context in the measure and potentially only returning 0 and if that is the case how would you go about to solve this problem.

To demonstrate my problem I have used the ContosoRetailDW sample database with a simple star scheme consisting in the tables "FactSales", "DimDate" and "DimProduct"

[image]

Comment: Can you post a .pbix?

Comment: You are iterating full fact table in [Total Product Sales Comparable] measure: ADDCOLUMNS(FactSales,"@CompRange",[C.........) This is wrong! Take a look at your rows on your matrix visual: Only products there! True solution: ADDCOLUMNS( VALUES (DimProduct[ProductName]),"@CompRange",.........bla bla)

Comment: Thank you @OzanSen for you respons! I think I'm quite close now with your suggested adjustment. It displays Comparable Sales Amounts now but only at ProductName level for each row. It does not seem to apply the ALL(DimProduct) in the return statement..

Comment: OK. That's because you removed all filters on product table by using ALL(DimProduct) in your measure : CALCULATE([Sales Amount],ALL(DimProduct),FilteredTable)

Comment: I want to remove all filters on DimProduct since I want to have a total product sales amount but the All(DimProduct) isnt working.

Comment: I have more images here:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-use-a-measure-as-a-filter-in-another-measure/m-p/2974896#M1016978

Comment: If you remove the filter from dimProduct, then you are removing the filter from the column [BrandName]. If you want to remove all filters(everything), you should remove filter from the fact table. It means no filter on the model except FilterTable! : If that's your aim, change ALL(dimProduct) with ALL(FactSales)

Comment: I don’t want to ignore all filters, only DimProduct so it returns the total sales amount for all products in that context i.e. Ignoring the product row context.

Comment: What if you try these 2 solutions :  ALLEXCEPT(dimProduct,dimProduct[BrandName]) OR ALL(dimProduct[ProductName])

Comment: `DimDate[Datekey]` is it a date column or numerical

Comment: @Mik Data type "Date"

Comment: @OzanSen For some reason this solution works:
sumx(filter(All(DimProduct[ProductName]),[Sales Amount PY]*[Sales Amount]+0<>0),FactSales[Sales Amount])
But not this:
Total Product Sales Comparable v1 =
var CompRangeTable = ADDCOLUMNS(VALUES(DimProduct[ProductName]),"@CompRange",[ComparableRange])
var FilteredTable = FILTER(CompRangeTable,[@CompRange] = 1)
return
CALCULATE(FactSales[Sales Amount],ALL(DimProduct),FilteredTable)

Answer (score 0):

This expression

```
ADDCOLUMNS(FactSales,"@CompRange",[ComparableRange])
```

is equal to

```
CALCULATETABLE(
   ADDCOLUMNS(FactSales,"@CompRange",[ComparableRange])
   ,Calendar[CalendarMonth]=2000805
   ,DimProduct[Brand]="The Phone Company"
)
```

so :

1 - `FactSales` is cutted by context

2 - ADDCOLUMNS applies a row context to `[ComparableRange]` measure
to EACH row.

For example you have a row with `FactSales[date]="01/01/2022"`; `FactSales[product]="iPhone"`; `FactSales[customer]="Bill Gates"` ; `FactSales[price]=200` ; `FactSales[qty]=10` Your `[Sales Amount PY]` in  `[ComparableRange]` will search `SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR()` on a day level, for the sample it is - "01/01/2021" most probably you have no sales for customer  "Bill Gates" that date, so `[ComparableRange]` will return you - 0

Try this one, it's not optimized, so just check if it works.

```
Total Product Sales Comparable=
VAR CurrentCalendarMonth = SELECTEDVALUE(Calendar[CalendarMonth])
VAR allProducts = 
        CALCULATETABLE(
            VALUES(DimProduct[ProductName])
            ,ALL() -- remove all filters and crossffilters from your data model
        )
VAR totalSalesAndCompRng = 
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            allProducts
            ,"@totalAmount
                 ,CALCULATE(
                      [Sales Amount]
                      ,Calendar[CalendarMonth] = CurrentCalendarMonth
                 )
           ,"@CompRange"
                 ,CALCULATE(
                      [ComparableRange]
                      ,Calendar[CalendarMonth] = CurrentCalendarMonth
                  )
        )
VAR onlyCompRng = 
        FILTER(
            totalSalesAndCompRng
            ,[@CompRange]=1
        )
RETURN
    SUMX(onlyCompRng,[@CompRange])
```

Your second measure:

```
Total Product Sales Comparable =
var FilteredTable = 
     FILTER(
         FactSales
         ,[Sales Amount PY]*[Sales Amount]+0<>0 -- returns false 
                                                -- the reason is the same 
                                                -- as above 
                                                -- and FilteredTable is empty
     )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        [Sales Amount]
        ,ALL(DimProduct)
        ,FilteredTable
    )
```

You can try smth like this:

```
Total Product Sales Comparable =

var FilteredTable = 
    FILTER(
        All(DimProduct)
        ,NOT [Sales Amount PY]*[Sales Amount]=0
    )
VAR CurrentCalendarMonth = SELECTEDVALUE(Calendar[CalendarMonth])

RETURN
    SUMX(
        FilteredTable
        ,CALCULATE(
            [Sales Amount]
            ,Calendar[CalendarMonth]=CurrentCalendarMonth 
        )
    )
```